# Pig Latin translator with too many `push_str`s

Tags: strings, rust

I'm learning Rust and one of the [challenges in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary) was to build a pig latin translator.

> Convert strings to pig latin. The first consonant of each word is moved to the end of the word and “ay” is added, so “first” becomes “irst-fay.” Words that start with a vowel have “hay” added to the end instead (“apple” becomes “apple-hay”).

I came up with the code below and I'm looking for ways to improve it, specifically reducing the `push_str`s and improving the `starts_with_a_vowel` method. How can the code be improved?

**main.rs**

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", pig_latinify("String me".to_string()));
}

fn transform_word(word: &str) -> String {
    let mut new_word = String::new();
    new_word.push_str(&word[1..]);
    new_word.push_str(&word[..1]);
    if starts_with_a_vowel(word) {
        new_word.push_str("h");
    }
    new_word.push_str("ay");
    new_word
}

fn starts_with_a_vowel(word: &str) -> bool {
    let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    for vowel in &vowels {
        if word.starts_with(vowel) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}

fn pig_latinify(statement: String) -> String {

    let mut transformed_statement = String::new();
    if !statement.is_ascii() {
        panic!("statement must be ascii");
    }
    let iter = statement.split_word_bounds();
    for word in iter {
        if word.trim().len() > 0 {
            transformed_statement.push_str(&transform_word(word));
            transformed_statement.push_str(" ");
        }
    }
    transformed_statement.trim();
    transformed_statement
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
...
[dependencies]
unicode-segmentation = "1.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Write tests

Unfortunately, your piglatify doesn't follow your rules. `apple` gets transformed into `applyaay`, but it should get transformed into `apple-hay`. Also, `first` should get transformed into `irst-fay`, but you will transform it into `irstfay`.

Rust makes it really easy to add tests to your code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use transform_word;

    #[test]
    fn empty_string() {
        assert_eq!(transform_word(""), "");
    }

    #[test]
    fn apple() {
        assert_eq!(transform_word("apple"), "apple-hay");
    }

    #[test]
    fn first() {
        assert_eq!(transform_word("first"), "irst-fay");
    }
}
```

While this only uses the given strings from the exercise, it already tells us that there is something amiss if we run the tests with `cargo test`:

```
running 3 tests
test test::empty_string ... FAILED
test test::first ... FAILED
test test::apple ... FAILED

failures:

---- test::empty_string stdout ----
    thread 'test::empty_string' panicked at 'byte index 1 is out of bounds of ``', /checkout/src/libcore/str/mod.rs:2217:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

---- test::first stdout ----
    thread 'test::first' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"irstfay"`,
 right: `"irst-fay"`', src/main.rs:57:9

---- test::apple stdout ----
    thread 'test::apple' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"ppleahay"`,
 right: `"apple-hay"`', src/main.rs:52:9
```

## Use `with_capacity` if possible

You can use `String::with_capacity` in `transform_word`. The new word has the same length as the old one plus four:

```
fn transform_word(word: &str) -> String {
    if word.is_empty() {
        return String::new();
    }
    let mut new_word = String::with_capacity(word.len() + 4);

    // still buggy, see above
    new_word.push_str(&word[1..]);
    new_word.push_str(&word[..1]);
    if starts_with_a_vowel(word) {
        new_word.push_str("h");
    }
    new_word.push_str("ay");
    new_word
}
```

However, we still need to fix the bug mentioned before:

```
fn transform_word(word: &str) -> String {
    if word.is_empty() {
        return String::new();
    }
    let mut new_word = String::with_capacity(word.len() + 4);

    if starts_with_a_vowel(word) {
        new_word.push_str(&word);
        new_word.push_str("-hay");
        new_word
    } else {
        new_word.push_str(&word[1..]);
        new_word.push('-');
        new_word.push_str(&word[..1]);
        new_word.push_str("ay");
        new_word
    }
}
```

## Alternative variants

Truth be told, that looks somewhat silly. We can just use `+=` instead of `push_str`, or even `+`:

```
fn transform_word(word: &str) -> String {
    if word.is_empty() {
        return word.to_owned();
    }
    if starts_with_a_vowel(word) {
        word.to_owned() + "-hay"
    } else {
        word[1..].to_owned() + "-" + &word[..1] + "ay"
    }
}
```

Speaking about alternatives, if you use [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) then `starts_with_a_vowel` can be written in a single line:

```
fn starts_with_a_vowel(word: &str) -> bool {
    "aeiou".chars().any(|vowel| word.starts_with(vowel))
}
```

Note that we use a `Char` as pattern, not a `String`. `starts_with` works with both, but this variant shows our intend to match only a single character.

## Ownership

It's not necessary to take ownership of the given `String` in `pig_latinify`.

Comment: Yup that is definitely what I was going for. I changed `transformed_statement.push_str`'s to `transformed_statement += &transform_word(word); transformed_statement += " ";` Is it possible to combine these into one statement?

Comment: @topher [`join(" ")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#tymethod.join) or [one of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941851/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-print-an-iterator-separated-by-spaces-in-rust).